# Already accepted offer but GPA is slightly lower than GPA threshold

Tags: job-offer, new-job

I recently accepted an offer by one of the big 4. As in, they called me with an offer and then emailed me an official offer letter which I have already signed and accepted. My recruiter had let me know that I don't need to send my GPA until a closer date.

I'm an engineering major, and my major GPA is easily above the threshold, however, my cumulative GPA (which is what they'll be asking for) is slightly below their required GPA. My overall GPA is dragged down because I underestimated the transition from high school work to college work and hence struggled deeply my first few semesters.

I'm worried that the company may withdraw my offer because of this. What should I do when they ask for my c-GPA and it's slightly below their required GPA?

Comment: Does the offer say it's contingent on your GPA?

Comment: It seems strange for a company that has a GPA requirement to extend an offer before seeing the GPA.

Comment: If they cared that much about the GPA the offer wouldn’t have come before knowing your GPA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What should I do when they ask for my c-GPA and it's slightly below
>   their required GPA?

When they ask for your GPA, you give it to them. If that disqualifies you, then they will tell you. Perhaps they will give you a chance to talk about it - that depends on the company's policies toward GPA. Some are more absolute than others.

Unless you can find a quick way to raise your GPA, there's really nothing else to be done here.

If you are very concerned, you could consider sending in your GPA sooner. That way, you'll find out if there is an issue sooner.